# What tense are wishes, not questions that start with "I wish..."

Tags: tenses

Given a wish of the form, "May he rest in peace," what tense is being used?

Comment: See page 5 of [Fillmore's "May We Come In?"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf). This is the "Magical sense" of modal auxiliary _may_, used in wishes, blessings, and curses. It occurs only in initial position. Oh, and since modal auxiliaries are not inflected for tense, it's either no tense at all or the present tense by default, depending on what church you go to.

Comment: @JohnLawler - Very good comment. If you make it an answer I think it's deserving of being marked as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

It's a rather old-fashioned usage, a formulaic [subjunctive](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=5088).

Comment: Though, of course, that's not a tense. :-)

Comment: Is that a mood marker, or are your keyboard markings as faint as mine?

Comment: Just a smiley, that's all.

Comment: I like the term 'Magical sense'. So magical, it seems to disappear entirely in 'God save the Queen.'